# Razorpay quick payment integration with contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, payment-gateway, contact-form-7, razorpay

I tried to send the form via E-mail after customer done the successful payment via Razorpay.

I used the **Razorpay quick payments** plugin for payment gateway and contact form 7, the issue is there will be two buttons for Payment button (Razorpay) and submit button (to send a mail-form submission) and I would like to have a single button as Payment.

When the user done the payment the user filled form should be triggered to send a mail as we configured in contact form 7.

Please give a solution, how can I get it

Comment: i am also looking solution for the same question...help me anyone know solution